# microtiter plate well selector in pyqt

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, qt-designer

I am working on a solution for processing data from microtiter plate assays using qt designer. The main idea is that a user can select a plate layout (6 24, or 96 well) and then group wells into treatments for analysis. My original implementation was to arrange Qcheckboxes in a grid layout representing the plate layout. The user could then check the wells that they wanted to include in a treatment. However, with large plates or treatments with a large number of wells the clicking can get a little tedious and annoying, especially with small checkboxes to click.

What I want to implement is a visual representation of the microtiter plate that would be interactive such that the user could click on a well, drag across multiple wells, or ctrl+click to select multiple random wells. Ideally I would like the well to highlight in some way when clicked. My only problem is that I'm not really sure how to accomplish this. Is there a way to use a Qgraphicsview that would allow the type of selection I am looking for? Or am I just out of luck here?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: I have no experience with PyQt or Qt Designer, but if you have the ability to embed some type of html panel, could you use javascript and css to do it?  That would probably be the simplest solution if you know how to do it with javascript / css.  Good luck either way!

Comment: @DuckPuncher I believe they have a widget for embedding html. I'll have to look at the docs, but that is a great suggestion. Thanks!